# Где можно найти классы для kaitai struct?

Tags: java, binary, yaml

Хочу начать работу с [Kaitai Struct](http://kaitai.io/), для обработки бинарных файлов. Изначально там требуется написать `.ksy` файл, который потом компилируется в исходный код на любом из предложенных языков - Java, Ruby, HTML, C++, Perl, PHP, Python. Это очень удобно.
Свои готовые классы на Java я в проект вложил, однако эти классы в качестве полей имеют объекты других "родных классов" Kaitai Struct:

> Add KS runtime library for your particular language into your project
>   (don’t worry, it’s small and it’s there mostly to ensure readability
>   of generated code)

таких как:

- KaitaiStream.java
- KaitaiStruct.java
- ByteBufferKaitaiStream.java
- RandomAccessFileKaitaiStream.java

Вот их-то я и не могу найти. Я изначально взял с [гитхаба](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct_java_runtime/tree/48322f4ca62a32ccb56453fc8285822c8fbfe5d2/src/main/java/io/kaitai/struct), но это не работает. Где можно найти эти классы?

Comment: какой системой сборки пользуетесь?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создатель проекта еще не выпустил **release** версию этой библиотеки, но есть **snapshot** и его вы можете взять [тут](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/io/kaitai/kaitai-struct-runtime/0.8-SNAPSHOT/), а затем подключить в своей **IDE**.

Но более правильным вариантом будет настройка системы сборки и пусть она сама забирает нужные вам файлы. Для **maven** нужно добавить следующую зависимость

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.kaitai</groupId>
    <artifactId>kaitai-struct-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>0.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

И указать правильный адрес репозитория

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>allow-snapshots</id>
        <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>oss-snapshots</id>
                <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
                <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
                <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Это отличный ответ, спасибо!